# Azure Deploy from TFS Server Build Fail

Tags: azure, tfs

So I'm trying to deploy to an azure site on build.

```
 packageFile= Find-Files -SearchPattern 
D:\GFDFinaeonAgent\_work\1\a\**\*.zip

2017-04-27T19:32:34.6377218Z packageFile= 
D:\GFDFinaeonAgent\_work\1\a\GFDFinaeon.zip

2017-04-27T19:32:34.6377218Z Get-AzureWebSite -Name GFDFinaeon -ErrorAction 
SilentlyContinue

2017-04-27T19:32:35.3302965Z ##[warning]System.ArgumentNullException: Value 
cannot be null.

2017-04-27T19:32:35.3302965Z ##[warning]Parameter name: key

2017-04-27T19:32:35.3302965Z ##[warning]   at 
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
```

As far as I can tell I have everything setup correctly.

```
New-AzureWebSite -Name GFDFinaeon -Location West US

2017-04-27T19:32:35.3615494Z ##[error]Value cannot be null.

2017-04-27T19:32:35.3615494Z ##[error]Parameter name: key

2017-04-27T19:32:35.3615494Z Publish-AzureWebsiteProject -Name "GFDFinaeon" 
-Package "D:\GFDFinaeonAgent\_work\1\a\GFDFinaeon.zip" 

2017-04-27T19:32:35.4084282Z ##[error]Value cannot be null.

2017-04-27T19:32:35.4084282Z ##[error]Parameter name: key
```

I have visual studio and tfs server setup on my build server. visual studio is connected to my azure.

Any help or ideas to troubleshoot? 
Thank you

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ0OS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up answering my own question.

I had to update my TFS server version. It was running on the original install version, when I updated it to TFS update 4 everything started running alot smoother and working correctly.

If you have issues where TFS server isn't acting right, check your TFS Server version. Build agents started working correctly, deployments, builds, and adding in extensions was added as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your build server likely has the wrong version of Azure PowerShell installed. The last supported version that I've seen is 1.3.2.

Ref: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureFileCopy -- required version 1.3.2

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment -- recommends version 1.3.0

Comment: i have version 3.6 installed. so thats not compatible with tfs and azure?

Comment: It's not that it's not compatible with "tfs and azure". It's not compatible with the build and deployment tasks.

Comment: So it looks like it wants me to install the old version of azure "Azure PowerShell Installer v1.0.2" and then add these tasks? how would i add these tasks. git isnt installed on the build server.

Comment: The tasks are part of your TFS instance. You don't need to do anything with them. Just install an appropriate version of Azure PowerShell.

Comment: unfortunately that didnt seem to work. i installed the 1.3.2 azure powershell and got the same error

Comment: Did you uninstall 3.6 first and restart the build agent afterwards?

Comment: i did uninstall.... but i didnt restart until now. so that got different errors.     The required module 'Azure.Storage' is not loaded. Load the module or remove the module from 'RequiredModules' in the file  &&    The required minimum version (0.8.10.1) of the Azure Powershell Cmdlets are not installed.

Comment: I commented out the line in the powershell script about storage because i don't think i need it and got back this error: packageFile= Find-Files -SearchPattern D:\Agent\_work\5\a\**\*.zip
 packageFile= 
  ##[error]No files were found to deploy with search pattern 'D:\Agent\_work\5\a\**\*.zip'

Comment: is this progress?